# Encontrar valores iguais entre 2 colunas de .csv diferentes e atualizar outra coluna X

Tags: python, csv

Olá,

Possuo dois arquivos .csv conforme abaixo:

.csv1

```
POS,ID
28000167,.
28000263,.
28000484,.
28000711,.
28000728,.
28000885,.
28089922,.
28089927,.
28090173,.
28090325,.
28090326,.
28090331,.
28090415,.
28090467,.
28096247,.
28096264,.
28096284,.
```

.csv2

```
POS,ID
28000167,rs75043266
28000263,rs151210258
28000484,rs7175266
28000627,.
28000711,.
28000728,rs140405700
28000885,.
28089732,.
28089847,.
28089876,.
28089898,.
28089922,rs12592271
28089927,rs113937352
28090008,.
28090173,rs12592307
28090325,rs187389297
28090326,rs74005248
28090331,rs113905655
```

Gostaria de atualizar os valores da row[1] do arquivo .csv1 com os valores da row[1] do arquivos .csv2 caso a row[0] de .csv1 esteja presente na row[0] de .csv2.

Neste caso meu arquivo .csv1 passaria a ficar como:

.csv1

```
POS,ID
28000167,rs75043266
```

e assim por diante para todas as outras iterações que ele encontrar...

O que eu tenho até agora de código não é muita coisa uma vez que não consegui nenhuma iteração...

```
import csv

csv1 = open("arquivo1.csv")
reader1 = csv.reader(csv1, dialect='excel-tab')
csv2 = open("arquivo2.csv")
reader2 = csv.reader(csv2, dialect='excel-tab')

next(reader1, None)
for row1 in reader1:
    next(reader2, None)
    for row2 in reader2:
```

Qualquer ajuda seria bem vinda!
Obrigado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Faça da seguinte forma:

1. Leia os dados de ambos os arquivos em um dicionário. A melhor forma de fazer isso é, na minha opinião, usando o [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader).
2. Processe cada item do dicionário criado a partir de CSV2, e adicione/atualize o valor sobre o valor da mesma "chave" (coluna POS) em CSV1.
3. Regrave o arquivo CSV1.

Exemplo de código:

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict

# Lê ambos os arquivos e armazena em um dicionário mapeando a chave (POS) ao conteúdo (ID)
csv1 = OrderedDict()
csv2 = OrderedDict()

with open('csv1.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        csv1[row['POS']] = row['ID']

with open('csv2.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        csv2[row['POS']] = row['ID']

# Processa cada item de CSV2 e atualiza o conteúdo em CSV1
for p, i in csv2.items():
    if p in csv1: # Remova essa verificação se quiser adicionar os itens de CSV2 inexistentes em CSV1
        csv1[p] = i

# Regrava o arquivo CSV1
with open('csv1.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=['POS', 'ID'])
    writer.writeheader()
    for p, i in csv1.items():
        writer.writerow({'POS': p, 'ID': i})
```

Se você estiver utilizando a [fantástica biblioteca *Pandas*](http://pandas.pydata.org/), uma solução que eu prefiro e que é muito mais sucinta e fácil é esta:

```
import pandas as pd

# Lê ambos os arquivos e armazena em tabelas do Pandas
csv1 = pd.read_csv('csv1.csv')
csv2 = pd.read_csv('csv2.csv')

# Filtra os elementos de CSV2 cujo ID seja diferente de '.' e cuja POS exista em CSV1
query = csv2[(csv2['ID'] != '.') & (csv2['POS'].isin(csv1['POS']))]

# Copia apenas a coluna ID da view filtrada de CSV2 para a tabela CSV1
csv1['ID'] = query['ID']

# Regrava o arquivo CSV1
csv1.to_csv('csv1.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Excelente! Entendi perfeitamente ambos os métodos! Eu já conheço o Pandas pois usei ele num curso de análise de dados do Coursera...
Porém achei que ele fosse mais utilizado para gerar gráficos e plots e acabei esquecendo esta parte de edição "básica" dele! Vou dar uma estudada melhor nele, visto que a maioria dos meus arquivos de data analysis são em csv!!!! Muito bom! Obrigado!

Comment: Por nada. Cara, Pandas existe exatamente pra ajudar com data analysis. Eu aconselho muito o seu uso. Boa sorte!